# Vptr in derived class of Multiple Inheritance

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void f()
    {}
};
class B 
{
public:
    virtual void g()
    {}
};

class C : public A,public B
{
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    cout << sizeof(a) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(b) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(c) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

why the size of c is 8 .But i think its size should be 12 because vptr is present in it.Please explain is vptr present in C or not.

Comment: Why do you think it should have a size of 12?

Comment: _@Arslan_ ***vptr*** isn't a thing in standard c++, it
s actually compiler dependent if one is used at all.

Comment: because size of C= size of A + size of B+ size of C where size of a and b is 4 ,4 bytes

Comment: vptr is present in all those classess which have virtual function ......

Comment: You also need to tell us what compiler and settings you are using.  I get completely different results [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e164d6d8ace0ef0e)

Comment: Will u please share your result and compiler name

Comment: @ArslanAslam What are you using? And share the complete result.

Comment: i am using visual studio 2012,my output is 4,4,8.

Comment: when i execute this code on c++ shell [ a onine compiler] ,i get result 8,8,16 which is again surprising.

Comment: Not surprising. You are using 32bit compiler. So it has pointer size of 4. That compiler is 64bit,  so pointer size is 8.

Comment: what about size of C

Comment: what do you mean by that? What size of C?

Comment: size of c is 8 but it should be 12 as i think because vptr is present in it

Comment: There are only two vptr in it. One coming from class A and other from class B. It can use vpty from parent's class.

Comment: Thanks You, i was waiting for that answer..

Comment: @ArslanAslam I added this discussion as answer. So please accept. –

Answer (score 2):

While size of any custom type is compiler dependent and can change with new compiler, new OS or without any reason, it is useful to know where it is coming from and what usually affect sizes of your types.

Any analysis will be based on particular impmlementation, so I will take g++ on Linux. Giving 3 classess you have (I added another virtual function to C for more insight), compiled in 64bit mode, I see following sizes:

`sizeof(A)` = `sizeof(B)` = 8, `sizeof(C)` = 16. Where those sizes come from?

`A` and `B` are easiest to reason about. They are very similar, and they do not have any data members. However, they do have a `virtual` function. Implementation of virtual functions in g++ is done through virtual functions table, and every instance of the class has a pointer to it. In 64bit systems, pointers are 8 bytes, so both those classess have the size of 8.

Now, class `C`. What's with it's size? One might expect it to be 24, right? 8 bytes for vptr of A, 8 bytes for vptr of B, and 8 bytes for vptr of C. But if you think about it, we do not really need a separate vptr for C. Instead, we could create a virtual table with methods of A, add our virtual function to it, and use a pointer to this new table. Thus we do not need an extra pointer there! We still need a separate pointer to B's table, so that object would behave correctly when cast to B.

Comment: Virtual table is reused? How sure are you? In gcc, it shows three separate virtual table.

Comment: @khrm, not a table, of course, I phrased it badly. A pointer. Will rephrase.

Comment: when virtual table is not reused.

Comment: @ArslanAslam It's vptr that's reused not vtable. That's what I was correcting about.

Answer (score 1):

This is all completely implementation dependant. A compiler doesn't have to use a vptr to implement virtual classes at all.

However, in your example, the C object and A subobject share a vptr, and the B subobject has its own vptr. Both are the size of a pointer, which in your implementation is 4.

Answer (score 0):

As has been remarked. Standard doesn't specify virtual pointer at all. And it is all implementation dependent.

Your compiler is 32 bit having 4 byte pointer size.
So A's size is 4. B's size is 4.

Now C has two vptr in it. One coming from class A and other from class B. It can use vpty from parent's class.  Now even if a new virtual method is define, it would reuse one of the parent's pointer. (In case of gcc4.8, it's A's vptr will be used as C's vptr)